# Find all a hrefs on a page and dynamically add a ng-click event to each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.3.x and have some content that is dynamically binded to a div as follows:

```
<div class="text" ng-bind-html="data.text"></div>
```

The data.text will usually contain a standard a href - I want to somehow be able to attach an ng-click event to each one of these links. 
Can anyone suggest how I do this... so in the view it currently looks like this within my Angular Controller to simply find these links and attach the ng-click event to each one.

```
<a href="/news">News</a>
```

// ng-click functionality enabled

```
<a href="/news" ng-click="preventEvent($event)">News</a>
```

Comment: jQuery('a').attr('target', '_blank'); You can add a attribute for href....Will this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood you question correct, but can't you do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('ng-click', 'preventEvent($event)')
  }
})
```

Comment: How would I get the click event handler to this?

e.g ng-click="preventEvent(event)"

Comment: What do you mean by "get the event handler to this"? The j-script will add an `ng-click` to each a element when the page is loaded.